# Sending core data to watchOS 2

Tags: ios, core-data, watchkit, watchos-2

I am trying to sync `CoreData` between iOS 9.0 and watchOS 2.0. My database is pretty small, so I wanted to just send the entire file over using the file transfer in watch connectivity. I know I need to find the URL of the `CoreData` stack and send that along with the metadata. I think I am getting the URL correctly, but I am getting a null error for the metadata. This is what I have tried.

```
let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let modelURL = bundle.URLForResource("Sunday", withExtension: "momd")!
do {
    let myStore = try NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.metadataForPersistentStoreOfType(nil, URL: modelURL)
    let fileTransfer = WCSession.defaultSession().transferFile(modelURL, metadata:myStore)
catch { 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata argument is not required and can be nil, which in your case I think will be fine.
Give that a shot

Comment: I think that works because I don't get an error and when I check the status a couple of ways, it looks like it has transferred. Unfortunately, the didReceiveFile command is not firing, so I can't really verify. I think that part is set up ok, but based on [this link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/40984#40984) it looks like there may be a bug. Has anyone set up a file transfer successfully yet? I can't find any sample codes with it working.

Comment: How large is the file being sent? Is the watch app running when you expect the file to be received?

Comment: I am not sure how big the file is. I did a file size on it and it was 136, but I know that attribute needs to be translated somehow and I am not sure how. It is a core data with two entities, one of which is empty now and the other has 2 rows by 3 columns, so it should be small. I have tried having the watch app running when the file is sent and also not running, then reopen once the file is sent. I have also tried having the didRecieveFile in both the interfaceConnection and the extension (I assume it should be in the interfaceConnection file) and none of them would trigger.

Comment: Yea, that sounds like a tiny file. Maybe try one of the other APIs like the transferApplicationContext and sendMessage to see if of them work? Either way, probably a bug report with Apple is the best next step. You should make sure to include a sample project, and then report back here with the radar number in case any apple engineers happens upon this SO question!

Comment: Ok, so Apple came back and said I can't send the directory, but I know you are aware of this because I saw your post on a similar question. I am at a bit of a lose because  I can't quite figure out how to serialize the core data directory, and I am not sure I fully understand the other transfer protocols. For example, if I have multiple changes that occur before the watch is updated, then the I don't think I can send multiple application context files. Does the transfer user info work the same way? Only the last is read? My file is so small, I would like to try to understand how to serialize.

Comment: transferUserInfo is a queue, so not like applicationContext. Each dictionary passed to transferUserInfo will get delivered to the other side in order. As for serializing the directory, just do a google/SO search for "objective-c how to zip up directory iOS"